# View logs in a single place for an application running in a clustered environment.

Tags: jakarta-ee, logging

I have a web application deployed in a clustered environment on Linux server and the logs are being written to a log file. Each instance of the application is writing to its own log file. To view the logs I have to open two Linux windows and monitor both of them.

I have two questions:

Is there a way to view the logs in a single window, without having to switch between two windows?

Is there a better design to have all the logs written to a single file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, I'll list a few options in this answer:

1. Write all logs to a common network shared location (eg. NFS mount). Then you only need to mount one location to access all the log files. If you applications all write to the same named file this could be problematic and require having them write to files with unique (perhaps node's IP as part of the name) names.
2. Some logging frameworks support the concept of appenders (eg. log4j). You could use an appender which aggregates the individual logs (either via e-mail to a central address, or to a database, or other logging infrastructure)
3. Use a logging infrastructure like [Kibana](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/kibana/) and [Logstash](http://logstash.net/) to aggregate and visualize your logs

Each of these options have trade offs in usability, complexity etc. You should also consider best practices in how you write out your logs which will facilitate easier traceability of things like requests, transactions etc. within your distributed environment. It's one thing to manage where all these logs go and how you view them but you also need to make sure you include enough relevant information to facilitate managing the challenges of debugging in this type of environment.